# How to pass a collection created without a model to a view file?

Tags: laravel

```
$mp=DB::table('miip')->get();
$mc=DB::table('mii')->get();
$mpc=collect([]);
foreach($mp as $post1)
{ foreach($mc as $post2)
  {
  if($post1->mipname==$post2->miname)
    {
      if($post1->mipvalue!=$post2->mivalue)
    {
      $mpc->name=$post1->mipname;
      $mpc->pvalue=$post1->mipvalue;
      $mpc->cvalue=$post2->mivalue;
    }
  }
 }
 } 
 return view('crud/ckv', compact('mpc'));
```

view file(ckv.blade.php)

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
      @foreach($mpc as $post)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$post->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->pvalue}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->cvalue}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
  </table>
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/mischkp', 'CRUDController@mischkp');
```

The program checks for changed values of products over a day. The program is working but the view file is not  accepting mpc.

Comment: Nope. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all three items back to the blade like so if desired:

```
   $data = [
        'mp' => $mp,
        'mc' => $mc,
        'mpc' => $mpc,
    ];

    return view('crud/ckv', $data);
```

You can test the object in your method before returning the view with a `dd()`

```
dd($data);
```

And to compare that the data is getting passed to the view you can dump each object on within the blade to see what in them with:

```
{{ dd($mp) }}
{{ dd($mc) }}
{{ dd($mpc) }}
```

Comment: this worked but the collection is only storing one item. I am planning to retrieve the data in an array and store it in a new table and iterate over it. Collection creates needless complication. Thank you for your kind assistance though.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable as usual:

```
return view('your.view', ['mpc' => $mpc]);
```

Or:

```
return view('your.view', (compact('mpc'));
```

Or:

```
return view('your.view')->with('mpc', $mpc);
```

Comment: @lamlichus please show the error you get. If you're not getting any error, show related routes and code you're using.

Comment: no error, only the values aren't being displayed in the view file.

Comment: @lamlichus if you want help, you need to show related route, the view etc.

Answer (score 0):

A small change in your code -

```
    $mp=DB::table('miip')->get();
    $mc=DB::table('mii')->get();
    $mpc=collect([]);
    foreach($mp as $post1)
    { 
     $temp = new \stdClass();
     foreach($mc as $post2)
      {
      if($post1->mipname==$post2->miname)
        {
          if($post1->mipvalue!=$post2->mivalue)
        {
          $temp->name=$post1->mipname;
          $temp->pvalue=$post1->mipvalue;
          $temp->cvalue=$post2->mivalue;
        }
      }
     }
    $mpc->push($temp);
  }
```

Comment: I am getting a collection of array of collection. I think it is better to store the data in a new table and iterate over it. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I haven't noticed, **$mpc->push($temp);** is on the wrong place. Try putting it inside the second **foreach()** loop. It will definitely solve your problem.